# Chef - Download multiple zip files from website(HTTP) and do some basic operations

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am writing a chef resource with a logic as mentioned with each steps

1. Search for a 'zip' content from the http website and download it
2. After downloading unzip the files and put it under a directory - for e.g /u01/var/
3. Now here comes the tricky part - for each downloaded zip file i need
   to traverse through each file and do the same operation which is
   applicable to different zip files

My Code -

```
require 'open-uri'
    links =  open(patch_depot ,&:read).to_s
    out1=links.scan(/\s*\s*"([^"]*zip)"/imu).flatten
    patch_files = out1.select{ |i| i[/\.zip$/]}
    print patch_files
     unless patch_files.length>=1
        Chef::Log.info('No latest file found..!!')
    else
    c = Dir.pwd
    Dir.chdir(cache_direc)
    patch_files.each do |patch|
      if ::File.exist?(::File.join(cache_direc,patch))
        Chef::Log.info("#{patch} file is already downloaded")
      else
        open(patch, 'wb') do |fo|
          fo.print open("#{patch_depot}/#{patch}").read
        end
        `unzip -qo #{patch}`
        Chef::Log.info("#{patch} is downloaded and extracted")
        FileUtils.chown_R osuser, usergroup, cache_direc
        FileUtils.chmod_R 0777, cache_direc

      end
```

So with the code mentioned above i am able to achieve point 1 and point 2

After this code block i have a ruby block which updates a file and i have a bash block which do some operation.

Like below -

```
ruby_block 'edit bsu.sh file' do
         block do
                bsu_sh_file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{bsu_loc}/utils/asu/mmy.sh")
                bsu_sh_file.search_file_replace_line(/^MEM_ARGS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"*$/, "MEM_ARGS='-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m'")
                if bsu_sh_file.unwritten_changes? == false
                        Chef::Log.info('No Changes need be made to mmy_sh_file')
                else
                        bsu_sh_file.write_file
                        Chef::Log.info('Changes made in mmy_sh_file file')
                end
        end
      end
```

bash block -

```
bash "test bash" do
action:run
code <<-EOH
some operation
EOH
end
```

My HTTP content may have multiple zip files
So for each zip file i need to unzip and do the operations mentioned on ruby_block and bash block

Kindly provide a solution or a suggestion

EDIT #1 : 
The Code written which is already a custom resource , I know i mess up with the loop some where. My code doesn't not moving inside the loop and iterating through the other actions.

Comment: Its confusing to know why are you stuck here. So, why cant you call a custom resource there and in which you get all the files at the location using `Dir` and normally iterate and apply your ruby and bash methods. I really don't get any clue of your concern.

Comment: Do you know beforehand the address from where you want to download the `zip` and the name of the file(s)? I mean, do you know beforehand the complete url from where the file will be downloaded?

Comment: @Navarro : yes i know the urls where exactly it is picking the zip files , Even i am able to get the list of zips like below [ "1.zip,2.zip,3.zip"] But i need to iterate first with 1.zip then unzip and do other actions which i am not able to achive

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of urls from where you want to download, you can have some attributes like:

```
default['your_cookbook']['files']['file_1'] = {
  address: 'http://whatever.com/file1.zip',
  name: 'file1.zip',
  path: '/where/you/want/it/',
  checksum: '12341234123412341234'
}
default['your_cookbook']['files']['file_2'] = {
  address: 'http://whatever.com/file2.zip',
  name: 'file2.zip',
  path: '/where/you/want/it/',
  checksum: '12341234123412341234'
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
node['your_cookbook']['files'].each do |file|
  remote_file file.name do
    path "/tmp/#{file.name}"
    source file.address
    checksum file.checksum
  end

  execute "extract_#{file.name}" do
    command "unzip /tmp/#{file.name} -d #{file.path}#{file.name}"
    action :nothing
    subscribe :run, "remote_file[#{file.name}]", :immediate
  end
end
```

I think this have the same functionality you need and avoid using custom resources in favor of the default ones, which are quite complete.

Comment: Thanks for the code, But this will work only for the known files in the website. In My scenario i do have files in the http may keep increases or decreases. Depends on the files on the website the resource should trigger the run.

Comment: You should specify this on your original question/comments, since what is understood from them is a different scenario.

For your particular case, I believe this is not what Chef is supposed to do. You can't reach an idempotent state where the number of files varies relying on an external source.

If you have a CI pipeline, maybe you can try to update there the attribute, but doing it 'all in chef' doesn't seem a good idea to me. Also, the chef runs are meant to be periodical and not triggered on third party events (Number of files in the server changing).

Comment: Thanks for your views. I am able to achieve it via accessing the http by checking source content of that file whenever its getting changed. But my question does not deals with the accessing/achieving the idem potency but i could not achieve the iteration with the code.